# Partition of Data with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
[
  {
    "setting": "Volume",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Brightness",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Contrast",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Contrast",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Contrast",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
    "counting": 0
  },
  {
    "setting": "Sharpness",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Sharpness",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000006"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Language",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000007"),
    "counting": 1
  },
  {
    "setting": "Language",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "counting": 0
  }
]
```

Now I want to `group` by `setting` and want only top most two data in result rest in `useless`

So my output should be after `sort` by counting

```
[
  {
    "setting": "Contrast",
    "counting": 2
  },
  {
    "setting": "Sharpness",
    "counting": 2
  },
  {
    "setting": "Useless",
    "counting": 3
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get away with it, then it's probably best to "stuff" the reduced results into a single document and then [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) the top two and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the rest:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$setting",
    "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "counting": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
     "data": {
       "$let": {
         "vars": { "top": { "$slice": ["$data", 0, 2 ] } },
         "in": {
           "$concatArrays": [
             "$$top",
             { "$cond": {
               "if": { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$data" }, 2] },
               "then": 
                 [{ 
                   "_id": "Useless",
                   "counting": {
                     "$sum": {
                       "$map": {
                         "input": {
                           "$filter": {
                             "input": "$data",
                             "cond": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$$this._id", "$$top._id" ] } }
                           }
                         },
                         "in": "$$this.counting"
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }],
               "else": []
             }}
           ]
         }
       }
     }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

If it's potentially a very "large" result even reduced, then [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) use a [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for the "rest":

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "top": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$setting",
        "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "counting": -1 } },
      { "$limit": 2 }
    ],
    "rest": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$setting",
        "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "counting": -1 } },
      { "$skip": 2 },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "Useless",
        "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        "$top","$rest"
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

Or even [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with MongoDB 3.6:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$setting",
    "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "counting": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 2 },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "top": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }   
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "colllection",
    "let": { "settings": "$top._id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$not": { "$in": [ "$setting", "$$settings" ] }
        }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "Useless",
        "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "rest"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$concatArrays": [ "$top", "$rest" ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

All pretty much the same really, and all return the same result:

```
{ "_id" : "Contrast", "counting" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Sharpness", "counting" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Useless", "counting" : 3 }
```

Optionally [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) right at the end of each instead of the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) if control over the field names is really important to you.  Generally I just stick with the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) defaults

---

In the event that your MongoDB predates 3.4 and the resulting `"Useless"` remainder is actually too large to use any variant of the first approach, then simple `Promise` resolution is basically the answer, being one for the `aggregate` and the other for a basic count and simply do the math:

```
let [docs, count] = await Promise.all([
  Model.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$setting",
      "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "counting": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 2 },
  ]),
  Model.count().exec()
]);

docs = [ 
  ...docs,
  { 
    "_id": "Useless",
    "counting": count - docs.reduce((o,e) => o + e.counting, 0)
  }
];
```

Or without the `async/await`:

```
Promise.all([
  Model.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$setting",
      "counting": { "$sum": "$counting" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "counting": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 2 },
  ]),
  Model.count().exec()
]).then(([docs, count]) => ([ 
  ...docs,
  { 
    "_id": "Useless",
    "counting": count - docs.reduce((o,e) => o + e.counting, 0)
  }
]).then( result => /* do something */ )
```

Which is basically a variation on the age old "total pages" approach by simply running the separate query to count the collection items.

Running separate requests is generally the age old way of doing this and it often performs best. The rest of the  solutions are essentially aimed at "aggregation tricks" since that was what you were asking for, and that's the answer you got by showing different variations on the same thing.

One variant put's all results into a single document ( where possible, due to the BSON limit of course ) and the others basically vary on the "age old" approach by running the query again in a different form. `$facet` in parallel and `$lookup` in series.

Comment: yes I got the result with the last two queries of `promise`... but obviously they will take time when there is large amount of data ??? isn't it???

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Don't leave multiple comments like that. You could have asked on a single comment. I'm telling you because in the last few days you've been doing similar things and others like "this is great" all over questions and answers here. Comments are used to clarify something and sent in a single request.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary You comments are clarified in the question since that is what we do.